# Javascript: Run function when onmousedown on any div except one

Tags: javascript

I need to run function: `hideLogin(event)` when the user clicks (`onmousedown` actually) anywhere except

```
<div id="loginForm">
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('body *').click(function() {
    if (this.id != 'loginForm') {
        hideLogin();
    }
});
```

Without jQuery:

```
<body onmousedown="onBodyClick()">
```

Code:

```
function onBodyClick() {
    if (this.id != 'loginForm') {
        hideLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will reference the id of the body as that is the object that you are clicking on, not the div itself.

Answer (score 1):

You may view a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qMEJR/.

The example creates 100 divs, with the 10th one having an ID of 'loginForm'.  Clicking on any `div` except for the one with the id of loginForm will alert the ID of the `div` clicked.

**JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(i==10){
        $("body").append('<div id="loginForm">LoginForm</div>');    
    }else{
        $("body").append('<div id="div-'+i+'">'+i+'</div>');
    }
}
$("div").click(function(){ 
    var obj = $(this);
    var objID = obj.attr("id");
    if(objID != "loginForm"){
        alert(obj.attr("id")); // Replace with function here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the function run when the user clicks anywhere, and add a condition so that it doesn't execute any code if the element is **loginForm**?